# ASP.NET Boilerplate with Blazor - just use the service layer?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Even though ASP.NET Boilerplate does not seem to support Blazor, is there any reason you could not use it instead of the MVC/Angular frontend and just consume the REST services provided in the ASP.NET Boilerplate Service Layer? Or are there better alternatives for that setup?

Thanks.